# Replica node automatically upgraded to primary node AWS Elasticache Redis

Tags: amazon-elasticache, redis-cache

I am using aws elasticache for caching, and i am using the primary node endpoint directly to write and using replica node to read.
The problem I am facing right now is, whenever the primary node is down the replica node is upgraded to primary node and the address for the primary node changes in my application configuration which is a hassel for me to change everytime.

I am here to ask if there is any way to solve this issue, the possible solution I thought of is if I use the Primary endpoint from the cluster rather than using the endpoint of the node directly.

Is it a better option to handle this situation?